# Replacing values in a list column using purrr functions

Tags: r, list, dataframe, replace, purrr

I have a data frame with a nested list column in which I would like to replace values in one of the nested columns based on values in another column, by iterating over rows using the `purrr` package.

I have tried using `map2` as per the example below, but am finding that the function is replacing the entire list/nested dataframe with a vector, rather than replacing only the target column.

I imagine I might need to use a nested call to `map` or something similar, but have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

Using the simple example below, for each row in the dataframe `df3` I would like to replace all values in `group2` in the nested `data` column with the value from `group1`, such that the columns in `df4$data` are preserved in `df4$data_corrected`.

```
df1 <-tibble(class = seq(1:5), group1 = c(rep("a",3),rep("b",2)))
df2 <-tibble(class = rep(1:5, each = 3), group2 = c(rep(c("a","b","b","a","b"),3)),  x = runif(15))

df2 <- nest(df2, data = c(x, group2))

df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "class")

df4 <- df3 %>% mutate(data_corrected = 
                     map2(data, group1, ~  replace(.x$group2, .x$group2 != .y, .y)))

df4$data

df4$data_corrected
```

I've successfully filtered rows using the above approach, but it does not translate to replacing values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

*After @nickb suggestion in the comments, there is a more generalized way of achieving the expected result by also keeping additional columns and* `sf` *objects.*

```
df4 <- df3 %>%    
  mutate(data_corrected = map2(data, group1, ~ {.x %>% mutate(group2 = replace(.x$group2, .x$group2 != .y, .y))}))
```

Output

```
> df4$data
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.266 a     
2 0.372 b     
3 0.573 b     

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.908 a     
2 0.202 b     
3 0.898 a     

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.945 b     
2 0.661 b     
3 0.629 a     

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       x group2
   <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.0618 b     
2 0.206  a     
3 0.177  b     

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.687 b     
2 0.384 a     
3 0.770 b 

#####

> df4$data_corrected
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.266 a     
2 0.372 a     
3 0.573 a     

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.908 a     
2 0.202 a     
3 0.898 a     

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.945 a     
2 0.661 a     
3 0.629 a     

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       x group2
   <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.0618 b     
2 0.206  b     
3 0.177  b     

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x group2
  <dbl> <chr> 
1 0.687 b     
2 0.384 b     
3 0.770 b
```

Comment: Thanks Ric, that approach produces the required output. However, my simple example includes only two columns, whereas the real use case involves nested sf objects with lots of columns. Can you see a way that scales up without needing to cbind each column in the output?

Comment: Hi Ric, I have just done some more playing around and a generalisable approach that handles additional columns and also sf objects is: `df4 <- df3 %>% 
  mutate(data_corrected = map2(data, group1, ~ {.x %>% mutate(group2 = replace(.x$group2, .x$group2 != .y, .y))}))`. I'm happy to give this a tick but might be worth editing to make this change. Many thanks, Nick.

Comment: @nickb Of course a more generalised method is always more than welcome! I'm going to edit my answer with your suggestion, thank you